# How to customize Python watchpoints callback to show only new variable value?

Tags: python, watch

How to print only new variable value with watchpoints in Python?

Like first example in documentation:

```
from watchpoints import watch

a = 0
watch(a)
a = 1
```

I would like to get out only number 1 and not:

```
====== Watchpoints Triggered ======
Call Stack (most recent call last):
  <module> (my_script.py:5):
>   a = 1
a:
0
->
1
```

Comment: Sounds simple but could you just use a print statement? Just curious if there is a reason this would not be sufficient to fix your problem.

Comment: I haven't used this library myself, but skimming the docs, I see the section [customize printer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/watchpoints#customize-printer), which might do what you want. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research; actually, reading the docs is the first thing you should do before asking a question, or if in fact you did but didn't see what you were looking for, you should say that.

Comment: I didn't mention that I checked documentation already with no luck. 
I tried to use a customized callback but there is no good example.